# Any two natural transformations between identity functors commute

Tags: category-theory, functors, natural-transformations

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category, $id_\mathcal{C}:\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}$ the identity functor. Prove that for any two natural transformations $\alpha, \beta : id_\mathcal{C} \Rightarrow id_\mathcal{C}$,
$$\alpha \circ \beta = \beta \circ \alpha.$$

---

Here is my solution:

Note that (is this step correct?) $\; \forall f:c \to d$ in $\mathcal{C}$, $$f \circ (\alpha_{c} \circ \beta_{c}) = (\beta_{d} \circ \alpha_{d}) \circ f, \quad f \circ (\beta_{c} \circ \alpha_{c}) = (\alpha_{d} \circ \beta_{d}) \circ f.$$

Since $\alpha \circ \beta$ and $\beta \circ \alpha$ are natural transformations (via vertical compositions), we have $$f \circ (\alpha_{c} \circ \beta_{c}) = (\alpha_{d} \circ \beta_{d}) \circ f, \quad f \circ (\beta_{c} \circ \alpha_{c}) = (\beta_{d} \circ \alpha_{d}) \circ f.$$
Therefore, $$f \circ (\alpha_{c} \circ \beta_{c}) = f \circ (\beta_{c} \circ \alpha_{c}), \quad  (\alpha_{d} \circ \beta_{d}) \circ f = (\beta_{d} \circ \alpha_{d}) \circ f.$$
It follows that (is this step correct?) $$\alpha_{c} \circ \beta_{c} = \beta_{c} \circ \alpha_{c} \; \forall c \in \mathcal{C}, \; \alpha_{d} \circ \beta_{d} = \beta_{d} \circ \alpha_{d} \; \forall d \in \mathcal{C} \; \Rightarrow \; \alpha \circ \beta = \beta \circ \alpha.$$

Comment: Why if the first step true?

Comment: There is a much shorter solution anyway.

Comment: @АрсенийКряжев I worked backward and found that for the result to hold, I need to have the first result. I actually don't believe that it is true because I can easily think of a counterexample. Anyway, what is the shorter solution on your mind?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider the diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
C @>{\alpha_C}>> C \\
@V{\beta_C}VV @VV{\beta_C}V \\
C @>{\alpha_C}>> C.
\end{CD}
Regard $\beta_C$ as just any morphism. Apply the naturality of $\alpha_C.$